# ACL, ls, "permission denied" and a lot of questionmarks

Tags: permissions, directory, ls, acl

I have two users, Alice and Bob. Bob should be allowed to list, `ls`, Alice's home directory. Alice also has a file in her home directory that Bob should also be allowed to read.

I run these commands as root:

```
[root@corvatsch ~]# setfacl -m user:bob:r /home/alice/
[root@corvatsch ~]# setfacl -m user:bob:r /home/alice/file
```

This yields the following result in the ACLs:

```
[root@corvatsch ~]# getfacl -c /home/alice/
user::rwx
user:bob:r--
group::---
mask::r--
other::---
```

and

```
[root@corvatsch ~]# getfacl -c /home/alice/file
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
user::rw-
user:bob:r--
group::r--
mask::r--
other::r--
```

It looks as if Bob should now be able to read Alice's home folder as well as the content of the her file.

When Bob tries that, he gets:

```
[bob@corvatsch ~]$ ls -l /home/alice/
ls: cannot access /home/alice/file: Permission denied
total 0
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? file
```

(**Note the questionmarks!**) and

```
[bob@corvatsch ~]$ cat /home/alice/file
cat: /home/alice/file: Permission denied
```

Looks like Bob can read the home directory, although in a weird way. Ls lists the file but seems to have problems with the ACLs?

And `cat`ing the file seems to not work at all.

Can somebody explain what i am missing?

**NOTE:** (I'm running CentOS 6.4)

Comment: Doesn't the directory (/home/alice) need executable access?

Comment: That solves it. So it looks like ls needs x permissions read the directory content. Probably makes sense. Thanks (Post it as the answer so i can accept it.)

Comment: In order to see the contents of a directory, a user needs x permissions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `/home/alice/` directory needs executable access for the user accessing it.

EDIT: BTW, the question marks are there to indicate that `ls` can't get the permissions on the file.